# Automatic redirects from http to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, https

I use the MVC pattern and my routing is as follows:

```
http://Myurl.com/class/method/param1/param2/...
```

Normally everything works very well But when I use the code below for compulsory use of https, my routing does not work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

.htaccess codes:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes


<Files '.htaccess' >
  Deny from all
</Files>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|eot|svg|ttf|woff|apk)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST} [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` means "only do this rule if HTTPS is off". Since you turned on HTTPS, it no longer does anything. Remove the condition. (Side note: The code you've posted doesn't do anything to make HTTPS compulsory.)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I edited RewriteRule but did not work again :(

Comment: For two reasons: a) you need a `[R]` flag to redirect and b) you've now removed your old `index.php` routing rule the site relies on.

Comment: I use `DirectoryIndex index.php` , so `%{REQUEST_URI}` should automatically call `index.php` . Is it wrong?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` will handle requests to `/` only.

Comment: Please tell me how to write `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

You need redirection. This should work for you. Paste it in your root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I do not think `RewriteCond` refers to the correct situation. I used `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_URI} ^http.*` but my routing does not work. The routing happens in the `index.php` file